# Active Directory search (PrincipalSearcher) trailing wildcard ultra slow

Tags: vb.net, search, active-directory, userprincipal

I am searching within the domain active directory and it is very slow when using a trailing wildcard.

Is there a good way of doing this efficiently? the wildcard at the end work almost instantly.

Here the sample code:

```
 User = New UserPrincipal(ctx)
 User.DisplayName = "*" AQT_Searchbar.Text & "*"
 Searcher.QueryFilter = User

 Dim UserResult As PrincipalSearchResult(Of Principal) = Searcher.FindAll()

 Dim AccountCount As Integer = UserResult.Count
 MsgBox(AccountCount)
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a medial search and it is expensive. You can ask the administrator to create what's called a tuple index on the displayName attribute - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676931(v=vs.85).aspx.

That said, making an inference from your sample, ambiguous name resolution may be what you want instead - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/243299.